# Baby/Papa/Mama/Big Rudin

Tags: analysis, soft-question

Recently, I was looking for the reviews of some Analysis books while encountered terms such as **Baby/Papa/Mama/Big** Rudin. Firstly, I thought that these are the names of a book! But it turned out that these are some nick names used for the books of **Walter Rudin**. So I was thinking that

$1$. What are the corresponding books of these nick names?
$2$. Why such nick names are chosen? or What are their origins?

Comment: Baby Rudin is *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*; I’m pretty sure that I was already hearing that name back in the early $1970$s when I was his wife’s student. Big Rudin is *Real and Complex Analysis*. Baby Rudin is an (advanced) undergraduate text; Big Rudin is a graduate text.

Comment: "Baby Rudin" is _Principles of Mathematical Analysis_, so called because it's the most elementary of his books and and its topics are prerequisites to the others. $\qquad$

Comment: Baby = Principles of Mathematical Analysis; Papa = Real and Complex Analysis; Grandpa = Functional Analysis

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Ow! :) And what about Mama and Papa? :)

Comment: @KajHansen: I haven't seen Grandpa anywhere! :D

Comment: @H.R. They are fine, don't you worry.

Comment: @H.R.: I assume that Papa Rudin is, as Kaj said, the same as Big Rudin, though I don’t think that I’ve actually noticed the name before; I’ve never encountered the name *Mama Rudin*. (That ought to be Mary Ellen, his wife — except that she didn’t write any books!)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Does *Lectures on Set Theoretic Topology* count?

Comment: @David: Borderline; I chose not to count it, but it wouldn’t be wholly unreasonable to count it. (I definitely didn’t forget it: I proofread the ms. and suggested a few small changes.)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In order to sum up the above comments, the corresponding books for these nick names are

$1$. Baby = Principles of Mathematical Analysis;

$2$. Papa/Big = Real and Complex Analysis;

$3$. Grandpa = Functional Analysis;

and it seems that the difficulty of contents of the books grows with the age of the nick names! Firstly, you are a baby and things are easy to handle. Then you grow up and become a papa and things get more complicated. Finally, when you are a grandpa you should take care of your legacy very carefully which needs a hardwork! So $1$ is a prerequisite of $2$ and $2$ is prerequisite of $3$.

Comment: Actually, Baby Rudin is not easier to grasp than Grandpa Rudin.